# dash: does ThemeSwitchAIO support State

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am working on `dash` app. I am using `ThemeSwitchAIO` to switch between the themes. I read in docs that theme will get applied instantly to all components except `figures` which we need to reconstruct. As I need to **display many graph figures** which gets populated from backend, I am thinking to ask for confirmation before theme gets applied using `dbc Modal` or `dcc ConfirmDialogProvider`. But currently I trying using simple `button` as `Input` and accessing `theme value` via `State`.

**Current Observation:**
As soon as I toggle theme switch, the theme seems to get applied instantly to the layout and on clicking the button it gets applied to graph.

1. Does `ThemeSwitchAIO` support `State`?
2. Is there any other way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Below is full working example:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State, no_update
from dash_bootstrap_templates import ThemeSwitchAIO
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

df = px.data.stocks()
theme_switch = ThemeSwitchAIO(
    aio_id="theme", themes=[dbc.themes.COSMO, dbc.themes.CYBORG]
)
graph = html.Div(dcc.Graph(id="graph"), className="m-4")
button = dbc.Button("Switch", id="button")

@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    Input("button", "n_clicks"),
    State(ThemeSwitchAIO.ids.switch("theme"), "value"),
)
def update_graph_theme(n, toggle):
    if n:
        template = "cosmo" if toggle else "cyborg"
        return px.line(df, x="date", y="GOOG", template=template)
    return no_update

app.layout = dbc.Container([theme_switch, button, graph], className="m-4 dbc")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```